# Is it possible to get javascript syntax highlighting and auto-complete in chrome dev tools live edit mode?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I love chrome dev tool, it has been a huge productivity boost for me.  I would love to find out if there is any plugin or way to get it to do auto-complete on javascript object (intelisense) and syntax highlighting in live edit mode?  In the console you can press tab to complete a javascript object, property or method, but that does not seem to be available in live edit mode.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auto-completion in the CodeMirror editor (should be enabled in the Settings) was landed yesterday behind a DevTools experiment "Enable text editor autocompletion" and should appear in the next Chrome Canary.

Regarding the syntax highlight, I'm not quite sure what your case is, since we always highlight JavaScript sources.

Comment: That's awesome thanks for that info.  I just pulled down Chrome Canary for windows, but autocomplete doesn't seem to be working even after I enabled CodeMirror editor.  Is Canary the most bleeding edge and I will just have wait a bit?  Thanks.

Comment: You are correct on the JS highlighting, I was just hoping for it to be a little more verbose like the default for sublime edit.  Thanks for all of the good on work on chrome dev tools!

Comment: Canary is the nightly build, actually, so that should be working. Can you file a bug at http://crbug.com/new and attach a [reduced] test case so that we can take a look at the failing autocompletion? Remember that you have to hit Ctrl-Space to actuate it.

Comment: Done, thanks for your attention! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=246345